# UNION join to email the set of rows based on the unique values in one column

Tags: sql, union, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to make union join on two tables , The output that i want is the rows from two tables for particular unique value should appear sequentially .

For example consider below :
If table A has values

```
C1 C2
a 1
b 2
```

and table B has values

```
C1 C2
a 5
b 7
```

then union should  look like

```
C1 C2
a 1
a 5
b 2
b 7
```

and also I want to email separately to some group of people, the rows in  table format  based on the Colum C1 values.

For e.g if where C1 =a then email those rows in email body to certain ids.

Comment: Show us your query attempt. (Should be a basic UNION.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
 create table tableA
    (
      C1 char,
      C2 int
    )



 create table tableB
(
  C1 char,
  C2 int
)

insert into tablea values('a',1)
insert into tablea values('b',2)
insert into tableb values('a',5)
insert into tableb values('b',7)



Select * from (select * from tableA
union
select * from tableb)
a
order by A.C1,A.C2
```

**Output:**

```
    C1  C2
1   a   1
2   a   5
3   b   2
4   b   7
```

Comment: I need to email the set of  values to specific group of people.

Answer (score 0):

Do the union in a subquery and apply the order afterwards, e.g.,

```
SELECT x.c1, x.c2
FROM
   (
     SELECT c1, c2
     FROM a
     UNION
     SELECT c1, c2
     FROM b
   ) x
ORDER BY x.c1, x.c2
```

You can also apply a WHERE clause to this subquery (more accurately: an inline view) for your email selection.

Comment: Okay this resolves the first part of the query, however i need to email the same set of values separately to specific ids.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate an email from your RDBMS? You should probably tag your question with the platform, or better yet treat that as a separate question.